# Prevent form submit when the javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have a mvc form with client side validations.

I want to make sure users cant submit the page if the javascript is disabled because then the validations will be bypassed. 
Is this possible, how can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One option is to control the form submission entirely in Javascript and leave the `action` attribute off of the `form` element.

Comment: Although my answer answers your question, I'm going to have to agree with nvoigt, always, always validate user input server-side before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although maybe possible, this is not a good way to solve your problem. Client side validation is no replacement for server side checks. You *must* do server side checks anyway, because nobody is forcing users to use your frontend at all. They could build their own webpage to submit data to your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what if i remove the submit button from page completely, is there still ways of submitting the form to server
?

Comment: @user2026343 sure, I could send the data to your server just the same.  The easiest way would be to have a proxy server in between that just inserts an enabled submit button into your page when I open it in my browser. "The client is in the hands of the enemy." Any client. Secure your server. That's security. If client side validation helps your users, great, get some. But never rely on it. Always assume that the client sends you a message with data it picked at will.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use Javascript to submit the form, using a button called Submit which isn't a submit button!

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitForm()">
```

JS

```
function SubmitForm()
{
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

With javascript disabled, clicking the button won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Default state has to be, that form can't be submitted (don't use action attribute), e.g.

```
<div class='error'>Turn your javascript to active form</div>
<form>   
...
Field: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" style="display: none">
</form>
```

And with javascript, append  tag behind  to hide message and show submit button:

```
<script>
    $(".error").hide();
    $("submit").show();   
    $("form").attr("action", "someurl.php");  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net mvc there is also a good feature `ModelState.IsValid` to check whether model validation has satisfied or not you can use that if somehow javascript is disabled in browser or somehow client validations bypassed..

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {
     if( ModelState.IsValid )
     {}
     else
     {}
 }
```

**Always try to use `ModelState.IsValid` in asp.net mvc because client validations are never reliable and also there is no full proof way to check whether javascript is enabled or disabled..the advantage of using `ModelState.IsValid` is that if whether javascript is enabled or disabled your form will submit and all validations for model will be checked on controller side also..**